# Why is my csv size shrink when I split it to different parts

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv with size 102GB, but when I use .to_csv to save the csv into parts, it become smaller. Each part has about 8GB size.

Code:

```
df.iloc[:100000, :].to_csv(f"part1.csv", index=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

Is there a reason why the shrink happened or is this normal?

Comment: How did the count of the number of lines change? i.e. if you run the `wc -l` command on the original CSV, then on every output file, do the two linecounts more or less agree?

Comment: to answer your question - no, splitting up a csv should not make it smaller, so if the sum of all the files is less than the original, then something fishy is going on. If the old csv had a ton of unecessary characters, e.g. `1.00000000000` instead of `1.0`, this could explain the discrepancy. pandas does parse the data, so the result won't be exactly the same. if possible, it's best to use a binary storage format e.g. [`parquet`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) for this much data.